# C#, Html Agility, Selecting every paragraph within a div tag

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How can I select every paragraph in a div tag for example.

```
<div id="body_text">
<p>Hi</p>
<p>Help Me Please</P>
<p>Thankyou</P>
```

I have got Html Agility downloaded and referenced in my program, All I need is the paragraphs. There may be a variable number of paragraphs and there are loads of different div tags but I only need the content within the body_text. Then I assume this can be stored as a string which I then want to write to a .txt file for later reference. Thankyou.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111332/select-all-ps-from-a-nodes-children-using-htmlagilitypack ? P.S. I don't know how to mark for duplicates..or maybe I don't have enough points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valid XPATH for your case is `//div[@id='body_text']/p`

```
foreach(HtmlNode node in yourHTMLAgilityPackDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='body_text']/p")
{
  string text = node.InnerText; //that's the text you are looking for
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that grabs the paragraphs as an enumeration of HtmlNodes:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("your.html");
var div = doc.GetElementbyId("body_text");
var paragraphs = div.ChildNodes.Where(item => item.Name == "p");
```

Without explicit Linq:

```
var paragraphs = doc.GetElementbyId("body_text").Elements("p");
```