# How to access the value of an HTML DIV tag with a given ID with C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to load the content of a `DIV` element in *HTML* into a variable so that it can be printed to an *HTA* file. However, I have about 70 other `DIV` elements in the document and I need to access one specific one. Is there a shortcut to accessing the content of an element with a specific attribute?

Here's a sample of the element I need to access

```
<div id='storytext'>
    <p>Story Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well with C# code you are not going to find the `DIV` unless it has a `runat="server"` attribute applied to it.

Comment: Are you using C# to parse an HTML file or is this on an asp.net page you've created?

Comment: It's not my HTML code, the program's goal is to download the source code of a page, extract the HTML from that DIV element then write it to an HTA file.

Comment: You can regex the HTML and return the div tag, or have you tried loading the HTML into and Xml parser and pulling the data out that way? *Most* HTML is basically XML, so this *should* work, but not always...

Comment: Aha! I believe I found a solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737757/c-html-agility-selecting-every-paragraph-within-a-div-tag?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're downloading a page that contains a DIV, programmatically, and you want to get the contents of that DIV?

Assuming you have the downloading of the page working, you might want to try the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  This library gives you a Linq to XML-like API for working with the looser standards of HTML pages.

If you don't want to do that, if the DIV tag were very predictable (has only the `id` attribute, or has the attributes in a particular order) you could use a regular expression to pull it out.  However, that would require so much fiddling around (given that your DIV has HTML content) that I would recommend just starting with the Html Agility Pack.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already pulling from two of my own libraries so I'd rather not have to go to another :P I do think I've found a solution in another post about the HTML Agility Pack, pretty sure it'll work here

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to pull out the content.

The code will look something like this

```
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.Load(rawHTML); // string containing the HTML content

var storyDiv = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Any(x=>x.id == "storytext").FirstOrDefault();
```

From there you can use `storyDiv.InnerText` or `storyDiv.InnerHTML` to get the contents. (Don't forget to check to make sure `storyDiv` is not null)